# How to generate pdfmark which opens at specific paragraph?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

We have the requirement to open a PDF user manual from our application at a context sensitive position. Since the manual is authored in MS-Word (2013), I managed so far to use a PRINT field and set a pdfmark:

```
PRINT "[/Dest /MyReferenceName /View [ /XYZ null null null ] /DEST pdfmark" \* MERGEFORMAT
```

When generating the PDF afterwards with e.g. FreePDF, I am able to open the document by adding the following to the Acrobat call:

```
/A "nameddest=MyReferenceName"
```

Only drawback is that the document always opens at the top of the page, not at the line where I inserted the PRINT field. So my question is

1. How can I create a pdfmark which then opens at a specific paragraph?
2. Is there an easier solution than what I did to solve the requirement under the given conditions?

Comment: What is the display scale when viewing the document? When jumping to a named destination, Acrobat/Reader attempt to get it to the upper left corner of the window, as long as there is more in the document than the window height.

Comment: @MaxWyss: I'm not completely sure what you meant, but for example, when having an A4 document and I have the above PRINT with the pdfmark set on a paragraph in the second half of the page and then open it via the nameddest, I see Acrobat Reader DC opening the document on the correct page, but with zoom factor window width, so that I only see the top half of the page, not containing the referenced paragraph.

Comment: You should see the bottom part of the page. Check the named destination location in Acrobat. Create a new named destination in Acrobat, and try opening it.

Comment: @MaxWyss: I don't have Acrobat, only the Reader. But why should the bottom part be any better? So the main question would be if it is possible to jump to a specific paragraph within the page when opening the document?

Comment: @AlexanderRühl, I am facing the same situation now. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanes: I didn't get any answers, so I stayed with the workaround that it opens the page only.

Comment: @AlexanderRühl, sure thanks for the response.